# Icon Overlay Handler for multiple icons

Tags: icons, shell-extensions

How to implement Icon Overlay Handler that can handle custom icons for custom files.

For example:

```
foo.bar - d:\myicon1.ico
bar.bar - d:\myicon2.ico
```

I tried used `IShellIconOverlayIdentifier` but it's uses as `one handler for one icon`

Answer (score 1):

Use [Icon Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144122%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead Icon Overlay Handlers.
See nice [Michael Dunn's tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/797/The-Complete-Idiot-s-Guide-to-Writing-Shell-Extens).